# Using -a warning in make4ht does not stop at first error

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

sometimes I like to use `-a warning` with make4ht to reduce the amount of information printed.

The big problem is that it does not stop at first error. It keeps running.

When I change to `-a debug` it stops at the error.

How can one use `-a warning` but make it stop at the first error?  Here is an example of `a.tex` which loads image `ZZZ` which does not exist. This is run using the command

```
make4ht -ulm default -a warning  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
```

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
My document
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZZZ}
\end{document}
```

Notice now what happens when I use `-a warning`

```
>make4ht -ulm default -a warning  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.

[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.

[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
```

Those are 3 passes it did. It did not stop at first error but kept going. Compare to what happens when using `-a debug`

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
etc...
(./a.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

! LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ZZZ}
                                          
?
```

And compilation stops and does not go to next phase. This is what I want. I just want the same with `-a warning`.

How to do that? In my builds, one tex4ht pass can take hrs. I do not want to wait many hrs only to find later that there was an error and I did not see it. I want my makefile to stop at the first error to save time.

ps. I did try all `a` [options](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/support/make4ht/make4ht-doc.pdf)

```
debug, info, status, warning, error, fatal
```

And only `-a debug` stops at first error. `fatal` does not display anything. So I have no idea where it stops as nothing at all is printed on screen (maybe because there was no FATAL error?)

```
>make4ht -ulm default -a status  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: a.tex
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

And

```
>make4ht -ulm default -a error  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./a.tex  15   LaTeX Error: File `ZZZ' not found.
```

And

```
>make4ht -ulm default -a fatal  a.tex "htm,mathjax"
>
```

**It will be great if there is an option that shows same level of output as -a warning but also stops on error just -a debug does**

TL 2022

Comment: try out all `-a` options, and if none of them fits your need, make a feature request. You should know by now that the maintainer is quite nice and willing to adapt things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. The `-a debug`  option uses the default LaTeX behaviour, so it prints all terminal output, and also stops on errors, like LaTeX does by default. In all other `make4ht` log levels, LaTeX runs in the non stop mode and the terminal output is read by `make4ht` and then parsed for errors or warnings.

In theory, you could try to run something like this:

```
 $ make4ht -m warning -m draft sample.tex "" "" "" "-interaction=errorstopmode
```

It passes the `-interaction=errorstopmode` to the underlying LaTeX compiler. It stops on errors, but as the output is suppressed by `make4ht`, you don't see any error messages, the compilation just stops and waits for your input. So this isn't really useful.

What I think could be useful in your case, is to stop the compilation on the first error. TeX compiler has an option for that, `-halt-on-error`. You can use the following build file to use this option with `make4ht`:

```
Make:htlatex { latex_par="-halt-on-error"}
```

When you now compile your file with:

```
$ make4ht -a warning -e build.lua sample.tex
```

Now, `make4ht` will stop processing your file on the first error, which will result in faster compilation.

Comment: Thanks, but draft is not an option for me, as I want final document build.  Problem with using debug mode is too much output and makes it hard to see where build is. I was trying to solve this by redirecting stdout only to /dev/null but for some reason, it is not working. Would you know why? Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkH4u.png)  I just typed `make4ht -ulm default -a debug  a.tex "htm,mathjax" 1> /dev/null`  but now I can not even ^C out  of it. It is stuck.

Comment: @Nasser and why do you want to stop on errors? I think the `warning` log level is good for you. Once you redirect the output, it will stuck on errors, but you will not see error messages. You should use `x` instead of `Ctrl-C` in that case

Comment: If I have a build that takes 10 hrs, I will not notice the error unless I am sitting looking at screen 100% of the time to notice. This is not practical solution. But with -a debug the makefile stops and so I can see right away the error on the screen anytime since it stopped scrolling. This way I do not waste time and get a build that is not complete and not know about it. I will just use `-a debug` and live with all the output because I need to stop the build when an error happens right away. but too much outpout also slows things.  So this is not perfect solution.

Comment: It will be great if there is an option that shows same level of output as `-a warning` but _also_ stops on error just `-a debug` does.

Comment: @Nasser it is not possible to hide output and parse it for errors and to stop on errors at the same time, I am afraid :/

Comment: If anyone can do it, it will be you ;). But there is something I still really do dot understand. If you want we can go to chat room instead of talking here OK. Simple question: when doing `-a warning` I see that make4ht saw there was an error, because it printed `[ERROR]` on the screen. Right? So somewhere inside make4ht the code knew there was an error. So my question is, why not simply stop there? i.e. right after printing the first `[ERROR}` message, the same code that did this, can exit(1) or stop using the lua code needed to do that. That is all what I am asking. What Am I missing here?

Comment: @Nasser `make4ht` parses errors from the log file, which is processed after the compilation, it doesn't parse it at the compilation time.

Comment: @Nasser I've edited my answer with an option how to stop the compilation on error.

Comment: Michal, thank you very much. I did quick test and it looks like it is working! Stops at first error.    ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unocj.png)   I will test it more on my main build more, but it seems this did the trick.  great job.